# Wetting properties of FTO coated glass

Tags: physical-chemistry, equipment, surface-chemistry

I am trying to spin coat a layer of polymer+Quantum Dots on an FTO coated glass slide. My material is forming agglomerates at the edges of my slide. My polymer is PVK which has a conc of$\approx 4.5mg/mL-4.25mg/mL$ while I am coating at only 500 RPM and I am still unable to form a film. Does anybody has any experience about forming films on FTO coated glass, or is it generally very reluctant to allow films to form on top of itself. Or is my polymer concentration too low?

Comment: There will be some agglomerates at edges of any slide using spin-coater. What does it mean that " I am still unable to form a film."? Could you specify  your results?

Comment: @JaroslavKotowski Yes, thank you very much for taking an interest, I measured an AFM image of the film and I saw non-uniformities and extreme roughnesses to the range of 60nm and was surprised and then did an AFM of the bare FTO slide and found that the roughness was almost similar to that of a bare slide, but since the AFM image is generally done only over a few microns of the surface, I couldn't/didn't do the entire sample but when seen with the naked eye by tilting the sample sideways, I could see a film along the edges of the sample.

Comment: Arising sidewalls after spin-coating is a quite common problem. I think that following articles could be beneficial for you: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1566119911003879
http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/nl025750g